# How I can download URL in background WebView (Android)?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to show a splash screen and in this time download the url in `WebView`. SplashView is a gif from assets which I create programatically

```
public class GIFView extends View {
private Movie mMovie;
private long mMoviestart;

public GIFView(Context context, InputStream stream) {
    super(context);        
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(stream); 
}
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    super.onDraw(canvas); 
    final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); 
    if (mMoviestart == 0) { 
        mMoviestart = now; 
    } 
    final int relTime = (int)((now - mMoviestart) % mMovie.duration()); 
    mMovie.setTime(relTime); 
    mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0); 
    this.invalidate(); 
}
}
```

where stream is

```
try {
        String path = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.subpath) + 
                      "/vsplesk.gif";
        mStream = getAssets().open(path);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How I can do this? Maybe somebody already decided same task. thanks in advance

Comment: use AnsycTask concept

Comment: i tried it, but in this case i have a issue. setContentView(webView) or my custom view?

Comment: ok can u post logcat plz?

Comment: in addition, after returning from AsyncTask how I can change view into Activity? Instead of splash show webView?

Comment: that u can do in post execute method of asynctask

Comment: i am already changed code. But I can restore this. Give me time

Comment: well, and where I should call method webView.loadUrl()? in doInBackground this is impossible, i think, because in this method we have not access of UI, or I am mistake?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18557451/826657 See this for asynchronous task.

Comment: yess right , u can use progressPublish method

Comment: WebView extends View and my splash screen also extends View. In new thread I can download url in WebView, but how after that i can change View in my activity?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do that by making an asynctask class

It'll run in the background then you tell it what to do once it's done loading/downloading in the background.

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

[Asynctask - Android developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)